# Combining Python3.7 asyncio and multiprocess for tcp server

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a tcp server that handles small amount of connections (about a 100, but could grow to more), but each tcp connection will be persistent and stream GBs of data off which I will be uploading to Elasticsearch database via REST API.

I have tried two independent ways (asyncio and multiprocessing), and I see MP has the data uploaded quicker, but at the cost of a ton of processes, and asyncio only uses 1 process, but the data takes about 5 mins to get into the DB.  I was wondering if there is a hybrid way such that have a batching mechanism to back 5 connections into a child process and run an asyncio loop in there to handle the connections.

Kinda what I am thinking:

```
async def dial_out_server(args):
    conn_handler = ClientConnection(args.elastic_server)
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        conn_handler.handle_connection, args.host, args.port)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
    #batch the connections and spawn a new process with a loop here.
    #Not sure what is best way or if that is possible
        await server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--host", dest="host", help="host", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--port", dest="port", help="port", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--elastic_server", dest="elastic_server", help="Elastic Server", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.run(dial_out_server(args))
```

Thanks

Full Code:

```
from utils import process_cisco_encoding
from telemetry_pb2 import Telemetry
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from struct import Struct, unpack
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler, QueueHandler
import grpc
import logging
import asyncio
import json
import logging 
import traceback
import uvloop

class Error(Exception):
    pass

class GetIndexListError(Error):
    def __init__(self, traceback, response_json, message, e):
        self.traceback = traceback
        self.response = response_json
        self.message = message
        self.exception = e

class PostDataError(Error):
    def __init__(self, traceback, response_json, data, message, e):
        self.traceback = traceback
        self.response = response_json
        self.data = data
        self.message = message
        self.exception = e

class PutIndexError(Error):
    def __init__(self, traceback, response_json,  message, e):
        self.traceback = traceback
        self.response = response_json
        self.message = message
        self.exception = e

class ElasticSearchError(Error):
    def __init__(self, response_json, message):
        self.response = response_json
        self.message = message


class ClientConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, elastic_server):
        self.elastic_server = elastic_server
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()
        self.log = None

    async def get_index_list(self, url):
        indices = []
        try:
            async with ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                    response = await response.read()
                    response = json.loads(response.decode())
                    for key in response:
                        if not key.startswith('.'):
                            indices.append(key)
            return indices
        except Exception as e:
            raise GetIndexListError(traceback.print_exc(), response, "Got Exception while trying to get index list", e)

    async def post_data(self, data_to_post):
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/x-ndjson"}
        url = f"http://{self.elastic_server}:9200/_bulk"
        try:
            async with ClientSession() as session:
                response = await session.post(url, data=data_to_post, headers=headers)
            return response       
        except Exception as e:
            raise PostDataError(traceback.print_exc(), data_to_post, "Got Exception while trying to post data", e)


    async def put_index(self, index):
        url = f"http://{self.elastic_server}:9200/{index}"
        headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json"}
        mapping = {"mappings": {"properties": {"@timestamp": {"type": "date"}}}}
        try:
            async with ClientSession() as session:
                response = await session.put(url, json=mapping, headers=headers)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            raise PutDataError(traceback.print_exc(), response, f"Got Exception while trying to put index {index}", e)


    async def init_logger(self, address):
        log_name = "dial-out.log"
        log = logging.getLogger(log_name)
        log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_name, maxBytes=536870912, backupCount=2)
        screen_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        screen_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        log.addHandler(file_handler)
        log.addHandler(screen_handler)
        return log

    async def handle_connection(self, reader, writer):
        try:
            HEADER_SIZE = 12
            header_struct = Struct('>hhhhi')
            _UNPACK_HEADER = header_struct.unpack
            address = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
            if self.log is None:
                self.log = await self.init_logger(address)
            self.log.info(f"Got Connection from {address[0]}:{address[1]}")
            while True:
                header_data = await reader.read(HEADER_SIZE)
                msg_type, encode_type, msg_version, flags, msg_length = _UNPACK_HEADER(header_data)
                encoding = {1:'gpb', 2:'json'}[encode_type]
                msg_data = b''
                if encode_type == 1:
                    while len(msg_data) < msg_length:
                        packet = await reader.read(msg_length - len(msg_data))
                        msg_data += packet
                sorted_by_index = {}
                converted_decode_segments = process_cisco_encoding([msg_data])
                for converted_decode_segment in converted_decode_segments:
                    if not converted_decode_segment["_index"] in sorted_by_index.keys():
                        sorted_by_index[converted_decode_segment["_index"]] = [converted_decode_segment]
                    else:
                        sorted_by_index[converted_decode_segment["_index"]].append(converted_decode_segment)
                index_list = await self.get_index_list(f"http://{self.elastic_server}:9200/*")
                for index in sorted_by_index.keys():
                    if index not in index_list:
                        async with self.lock:
                            index_list = await self.get_index_list(f"http://{self.elastic_server}:9200/*")
                            if index not in index_list:
                                self.log.info("Acciqured lock to put index in elasticsearch")
                                response = await self.put_index(index)
                                if response.status is not 200:
                                    raise ElasticSearchError(await response.json(), "Unable to put index into Elasticsearch")
                                else:
                                    index_list.append(index)
                    else:
                        segment_list = sorted_by_index[index]
                        elastic_index = {'index': {'_index': f'{index}'}}
                        payload_list = [elastic_index]
                        for segment in segment_list:
                            segment.pop('_index', None)
                            payload_list.append(segment)
                            payload_list.append(elastic_index)
                        payload_list.pop()
                        data_to_post = '\n'.join(json.dumps(d) for d in payload_list)
                        data_to_post += '\n'                        
                        response = await self.post_data(data_to_post)
                        if response.status is not 200:
                            raise ElasticSearchError(await response.json(), "Unable to put data into Elasticsearch")
        except  GetIndexListError as e:
            self.log.error(e.message)
            self.log.error(e.traceback)
            self.log.error(e.response)
            self.log.error(e.exception)
            await writer.drain()
            self.log.error(f"Closing connection from {address[0]}")
            writer.close()
        except PostDataError as e:
            self.log.error(e.message)
            self.log.error(e.traceback)
            self.log.error(e.response)
            self.log.error(e.exception)
            self.log.error(e.data)
            await writer.drain()
            self.log.error(f"Closing connection from {address[0]}")
            writer.close()
        except PutIndexError as e:
            self.log.error(e.message)
            self.log.error(e.traceback)
            self.log.error(e.response)
            await writer.drain()
            self.log.error(f"Closing connection from {address[0]}")
            writer.close()
        except ElasticSearchError as e:
            self.log.error(e.message)
            self.log.error(e.response)
            await writer.drain()
            self.log.error(f"Closing connection from {address[0]}")
            writer.close()
        except Exception as e:
            self.log.error(e)
            self.log.error(traceback.print_exc())
            await writer.drain()
            self.log.error(f"Closing connection from {address[0]}")
            writer.close()




async def dial_out_server(args):
    conn_handler = ClientConnection(args.elastic_server)
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        conn_handler.handle_connection, args.host, args.port)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--host", dest="host", help="host", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--port", dest="port", help="port", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--elastic_server", dest="elastic_server", help="Elastic Server", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.run(dial_out_server(args))
```

Comment: if the use-case is passing network traffic with little if any cpu intensive processing, asyncio should work just fine.  the tricky bit is making sure it's asyncio all the way down.  for uploading lots of data via http rest calls, aiohttp has you covered: https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#streaming-uploads

Comment: @LexScarisbrick I added the full code I am using and I am still a bit new to asyncio, but to me this should work, but again it looks like it takes 5 mins to upload the full info. Is there anything I am missing? Thanks